# Laravel withCount() returns wrong value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my application there are **users** making **pictures** of **items**. The relationship structure is as follows:

**Categories** -> **SubCategories** -> **Items** -> **Pictures** -> **Users**

Now, there's also a shortcut relationship called **itemPics** between **categories** <--> **pictures** so that the number of pictures uploaded by a user can be quickly counted per category using *withCount()*.

These are the relationships on the **Category** model:

```
public function subcategories() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategory');
}

public function items()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Item', 'App\SubCategory');
}

public function itemPics()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Item', 'App\SubCategory')
    ->join('pictures','items.id','=','pictures.item_id')
    ->select('pictures.*');
}
```

---

***My problem*** is getting the number of pictures that a user has gathered per category. The *itemPics_count* column created by withCount() always has the same value as *items_count*, even though the number of related models for both relations given by *with()* are different in the JSON output.

---

```
        $authorPics = Category::with(['SubCategories', 'SubCategories.items' => function ($q) use ($author_id) {
                $q->with(['pictures' => function ($q) use ($author_id) {
                    $q->where('user_id', $author_id);
                }]);
            }])
        ->with('itemPics') /* added this to check related models in output */
        ->withCount(['items','itemPics'])
        ->get();
        dd($authorPics);
```

This does not make sense to me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might help showing the relationship methods in your model (specifically items and itemPics)

Comment: Relationships added. See edit.

Comment: withCount tracks until your relationship stop, it ignores join clause, are you try to get the number of pictures only?

Comment: withCount kicks in immediately with your select clause whereas with kicks in with another query, so your join clause will not be treated for withCount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was worked for me:

```
//...
public function itemPics()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Item', 'App\SubCategory');
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
$authorPics = Category::with(['SubCategories', 'SubCategories.items' => function ($q) use ($author_id) {
      $q->with(['pictures' => function ($q) use ($author_id) {
         $q->where('user_id', $author_id);
      }]);
   }])
   ->with('itemPics') /* added this to check related models in output */
   ->withCount(['items','itemPics' => function($query){
      $query->join('pictures','items.id','=','pictures.item_id')
         ->select('pictures.*');
   }])
   ->get();
dd($authorPics);
```

Link to more information about Laravel withCount function here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Answer (score 1):

Withcount() function is not work properly if relations include join. it works only table to table relations.

```
    public function itemPics()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Item', 'App\SubCategory')
    ->select('pictures.*');
}
```